# 2D array passed in function prototype

Tags: c++

Here is my code in c++.

```
void multTable(int arr[][], int maxNum);
```

Before the main method, I declared this function prototype and then defined it after the main method towards the bottom of my code. However, I get an error stating that multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions. I don't understand how I can fix this.

Comment: What is `maxNum` ? Is it related to array dimension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your 2D arrays will have a fixed column size.  You can do this:

```
void multTable(int arr[][MAX_COLS], int maxNum);
```

You'll have to call it like this:

```
#define MAX_ROWS (5)
#define MAX_COLS (7)

int arr[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {...};
multTable(arr, 7);
```

Comment: I get an error that says use of parameters 'rows' and 'col' outside function body.

Comment: @user2548635 Sorry, I made a mistake.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this prototype:

```
template <int ROW, int COLUMN>
void multTable(int (&arr)[ROW][COLUMN], int maxNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the second dimension of the array. Otherwise the compiler could not dereference your pointer. That's why your compiler is generating an error

```
#define N 10 // just an exemple

void multTable(int arr[][N], int maxNum); // N is the 2nd dimention
```